# Travis checkstyle warning

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle, travis-ci

I started using CheckStyle in combination with Gradle and Travis CI. Now I want that the Build will be marked as "warning" if there are style errors. Can you help me making these settings?

.travis.yml:

```
language: java
sudo: false
jdk:
    - oraclejdk8
    - oraclejdk7
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    checkstyle group: 'com.puppycrawl.tools', name: 'checkstyle', version: '6.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.github.lalyos', name: 'jfiglet', version: '0.0.5'
}
jar {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'io.github.laufi.heisserdraht.Main'
    }
}
```

My Checkstyle configuration is the regular Google configuration:

```
<property name="severity" value="warning"/>

<!-- Checks for whitespace                               -->
<!-- See http://checkstyle.sf.net/config_whitespace.html -->
    <module name="FileTabCharacter">
        <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
    </module>

<module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="OuterTypeFilename"/>
    <module name="IllegalTokenText">
        <property name="tokens" value="STRING_LITERAL, CHAR_LITERAL"/>
        <property name="format" value="\\u00(08|09|0(a|A)|0(c|C)|0(d|D)|22|27|5(C|c))|\\(0(10|11|12|14|15|42|47)|134)"/>
        <property name="message" value="Avoid using corresponding octal or Unicode escape."/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharacters">
        <property name="allowEscapesForControlCharacters" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowByTailComment" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowNonPrintableEscapes" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LineLength">
        <property name="max" value="100"/>
        <property name="ignorePattern" value="^package.*|^import.*|a href|href|http://|https://|ftp://"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
    <module name="OneTopLevelClass"/>
    <module name="NoLineWrap"/>
    <module name="EmptyBlock">
        <property name="option" value="TEXT"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_SWITCH"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NeedBraces"/>
    <module name="LeftCurly">
        <property name="maxLineLength" value="100"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RightCurly"/>
    <module name="RightCurly">
        <property name="option" value="alone"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, LITERAL_DO, STATIC_INIT, INSTANCE_INIT"/>
    </module>
    <module name="WhitespaceAround">
        <property name="allowEmptyConstructors" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowEmptyMethods" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowEmptyTypes" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowEmptyLoops" value="true"/>
        <message key="ws.notFollowed"
         value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not followed by whitespace."/>
         <message key="ws.notPreceded"
         value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
    </module>
    <module name="OneStatementPerLine"/>
    <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
    <module name="MissingSwitchDefault"/>
    <module name="FallThrough"/>
    <module name="UpperEll"/>
    <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
    <module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
        <property name="allowNoEmptyLineBetweenFields" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
        <property name="tokens" value="DOT"/>
        <property name="option" value="nl"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
        <property name="tokens" value="COMMA"/>
        <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
    </module>
    <module name="PackageName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z]+(\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
         value="Package name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="TypeName">
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
         value="Type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="MemberName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
         value="Member name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParameterName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
         value="Parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="LocalVariableName">
        <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
        <property name="allowOneCharVarInForLoop" value="true"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
         value="Local variable name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="ClassTypeParameterName">
        <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
         value="Class type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodTypeParameterName">
        <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
         value="Method type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoFinalizer"/>
    <module name="GenericWhitespace">
        <message key="ws.followed"
         value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is followed by whitespace."/>
         <message key="ws.preceded"
         value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is preceded with whitespace."/>
         <message key="ws.illegalFollow"
         value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' should followed by whitespace."/>
         <message key="ws.notPreceded"
         value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
    </module>
    <module name="Indentation">
        <property name="basicOffset" value="2"/>
        <property name="braceAdjustment" value="0"/>
        <property name="caseIndent" value="2"/>
        <property name="throwsIndent" value="4"/>
        <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="4"/>
        <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="2"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AbbreviationAsWordInName">
        <property name="ignoreFinal" value="false"/>
        <property name="allowedAbbreviationLength" value="1"/>
    </module>
    <module name="OverloadMethodsDeclarationOrder"/>
    <module name="VariableDeclarationUsageDistance"/>
    <module name="CustomImportOrder">
        <property name="thirdPartyPackageRegExp" value=".*"/>
        <property name="specialImportsRegExp" value="com.google"/>
        <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
        <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="STATIC###SPECIAL_IMPORTS###THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE###STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodParamPad"/>
    <module name="OperatorWrap">
        <property name="option" value="NL"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="BAND, BOR, BSR, BXOR, DIV, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAND, LE, LITERAL_INSTANCEOF, LOR, LT, MINUS, MOD, NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, QUESTION, SL, SR, STAR "/>
    </module>
    <module name="AnnotationLocation">
        <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AnnotationLocation">
        <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
        <property name="allowSamelineMultipleAnnotations" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NonEmptyAtclauseDescription"/>
    <module name="JavadocTagContinuationIndentation"/>
    <module name="SummaryJavadocCheck">
        <property name="forbiddenSummaryFragments" value="^@return the *|^This method returns |^A [{]@code [a-zA-Z0-9]+[}]( is a )"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocParagraph"/>
    <module name="AtclauseOrder">
        <property name="tagOrder" value="@param, @return, @throws, @deprecated"/>
        <property name="target" value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
        <property name="scope" value="public"/>
        <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowMissingThrowsTags" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowMissingReturnTag" value="true"/>
        <property name="minLineCount" value="2"/>
        <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override, Test"/>
        <property name="allowThrowsTagsForSubclasses" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodName">
        <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"/>
        <message key="name.invalidPattern"
         value="Method name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="SingleLineJavadoc"/>
</module>
```

Comment: Does Travis support something like "warning" build?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [Violations Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-gradle-plugin), but that can only fail the build and not warn. Your `.travis.yml` will need something like:

```
...
script:
  - ./build.sh
  - 'if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" != "false" ]; then bash ./gradlew check -PdiffFrom=$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH -PdiffTo=$TRAVIS_BRANCH ; fi'
...
```

And in the `build.gradle` set:

```
...
 diffFrom = project.properties.diffFrom // Can be empty (ignored), Git-commit or any Git-reference
 diffTo = project.properties.diffTo // Same as above
 diffMaxViolations = 99 // Will fail the build if number of violations, in the diff within from/to, is higher
...
```

There are more details in the readme.

Another idea is to use [Violation Comments to GitHub](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violation-comments-to-github-gradle-plugin) to report the violations as comments in the pull request.